# Gimp на Linux Ubuntu 18.04. Проблема установленных шрифтов: вместо букв отображаются квадраты

Tags: linux, ubuntu, шрифты, графика, редактор

Скачала шрифты с русскими и английскими буквами для GIMP с сайта https://www.fonts-online.ru, формат ttf. Поместила в пользовательский каталог, все отобразилось. Но при попытке написать слово любым из этих шрифтов в Gimp вместо букв обоих языков и цифр отображаются маленькие квадратики (даже размер поменять нельзя). В LibreOffice все отображается нормально - но тут я, естественно, пользовалась другим механизмом установки.
Что не так? Как это исправить?

Comment: С этого сайта (шрифты спецом для GIMP) https://uroki-gimp.ru/adds/fonts/page/3 качает нормально

Comment: Кинула в `~/.fonts/`?

Comment: Попробовать механизм уже рабочий для LibreOffice.

Comment: Убедитесь что онные шрифты поддерживаются движком GIMP'a https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-using-fonts.html

Comment: @Hellseher, я просто нажала кнопку "установить", после чего шрифт скопировался в папку ~/.local/share/fonts

Comment: @donRumata, нет, в папки со шрифтами конкретно для GIMP (в обе директории, указанные в "параметрах") -- /usr/share/gimp/2.0/fonts и ~/snap/gimp/189/.config/GIMP/2.10/fonts

Comment: @Hellseher, спасибо, ознакомлюсь с информацией по этой ссылке.

Comment: Можно конкретный шрифт? Попробую у себя воспроизвести.

Comment: @donRumata http://allfont.ru/download/truegritctt/